# CookieContainer manual cookie override

Tags: c#, cookiecontainer

Hello i'm having slight problem when setting one cookie. I am using HttpWebRequest class to send my requests. And this code to set cookie i need:

```
    CookieContainer myContainer = new CookieContainer();
    myContainer.Add(new Uri("address"), new Cookie("cookie", "val1,val2"));
```

But that throws error

> The 'Value'='val1,val2' part of the cookie is invalid.

I have also tried UrlEncoding cookie like:

```
    new Cookie("cookie", HttpUtility.UrlEncode("val1,val2"))
```

But cookie turns into `Cookie: cookie=val1%2cval2` which is rejected by webpage.

I have also tried using quotes around the value part:

```
    new Cookie("cookie", "\"val1,val2\""))
```

But this one is also rejected by website.

Maybe anyone know a way how i could manually override cookie value to what i need without triggering error?

Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
new Cookie("cookie", HttpUtility.UrlEncode("val1%2Cval2"))
```

%2C is like a comma :)

Answer (score 0):

Do this to set the cookie

```
new Cookie("cookie", Server.UrlEncode("val1,val2"))
```

and use `Server.UrlDecode` to get the original cookie value.